# Plotting simulated data points from f(X)+e using R

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, simulation

Below is a chart from An Introduction to Statistical Learning by Hastie and Tibshirani. The authors use the chart to explain overfitting.

In the chart, Y is the response variable and X is the predictor variable. The black line represents the true model $f$. The circles represent data points from that model, given by $f(X)+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the random error with mean 0 and is independent of $X$.

I want to know how to plot the circles and the black curve in R, along with the assumptions that I have to make to produce something roughly 'of the sort'. $f$ looks like a cubic function to me.

[image]

Comment: The blue line looks like the true model. The black line looks like a polynomial approximation.

Comment: The true model is unknown. If the authors say the black is true, I think we can't argue? Or can we?

Comment: Who's to say? It might be a typo. The black line fits quite poorly at the far left, the blue line fits well throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal implementation of this kind of thing using ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)

signal <- function(x) {x*(x-.9)^2}
x_linspace <- seq(0, 1, by = .01)
x_data <- runif(101, 0, 1)
y_true <- signal(x_linspace)
y_data <- signal(x_data) + rnorm(length(x_data), 0, .025)

plot_data <- data.frame(
  x_linspace=x_linspace, x_data=x_data, y_true=y_true, y_data=y_data
)

mm <- lm(y_data ~ poly(x_data, 2), data=plot_data)
plot_data$y_preds <- predict(mm, newdata=plot_data)

p <- (ggplot(data=plot_data) 
        + geom_point(aes(x=x_data, y=y_data))  # Scatter plot of data.
        + geom_line(aes(x=x_linspace, y=y_true))  # The true signal.
        + geom_line(aes(x=x_data, y=y_preds), color="blue")  # The fit parabola.
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. For `predict()`, `plot_data` is supplied as `newdata`. How does the function know that we want to predict values using `mm` with `x_data`?

Comment: That's a good question, and gets a bit deep into R's mechanics.  The `predict` function is whats called a *generic function*, which means it can derive some of it's behavior from the type of its first argument.  Practically, when `predict` sees a linear model object as its first argument, it know that it needs to pull out the stored model formula, and that will tell it what to do with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your function $f(x)$; let's say $f(x)=x^3$ :

`f <- function(x) x^3`

(This function is vectorized: given a vector, it will cube each element of the vector.)

Define your set of $X$'s; the following gives you (1,3,...,99),for example:

`X <- seq(1,99,2)`

Generate some noise (standard normal here):

`error <- rnorm(length(X),0,1)`

Then you can generate the plot:

`plot(X,f(X)+error,xlab="X",ylab="Y")
points(X,f(X),type='l')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted Matthew's because he shows me how to produce a chart that looks like the one in my question.